# How to fetch creation date and volumes allocated for about 4000 datasets in dasd

Tags: mainframe

I want to fetch creation date and volumes allocated for about 4000 datasets in dasd .how can i do it? whether there is any command for it

Comment: Is part of the problem building the list of dataset names that you need the creation date/volume information for? Or, do you already have a list, in a file for example, of the 4,000 datasets. In either case, the TSO command: LISTDS `dataset` HISTORY will do the job. Your best bet would be to do this from a REXX program. If you need help grabbing/formatting the TSO output with REXX we can probably help with that too - I'm assuming you are on an IBM mainframe. Hope that was good assumption!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [catalog search interface](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=catalogs-catalog-search-interface-users-guide) and Rexx.  I believe the [DSCRDT2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=directory-catalog-field-names) field is what you're looking for.  A [sample](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=programs-iggcsirx) is provided.

You could use ISPF in batch, write a clist or Rexx program and use the [LMDLIST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-lmdlist-list-data-sets) service.

There's also [DCOLLECT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-dcollect).

Comment: It takes a bit of sophistication to use the DFSMS programming interface. I suspect that using the canned DFSMS utilities for TSO such as LISTDS under REXX might be a little easier in this case.