# reference information data (i) of pds/ps using jcl

Tags: jcl

i want to use the referenced date of pds/ps in my JCL.
is there any way i can do it?

i basically want to delete several ps which have not been referenced in the past 2 months using JCL..

Comment: I suggest you look at [this][1] short thread.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6703231/624463

Comment: was looking for parameter similar to EXPDT for DD statement..
looking to do this using JCL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DFDMSdss (PGM=ADRDSSU) for this task. Chapter 9 of the DFDMSdss Storage Administration book describes how to use ADRDSSU to manage DASD space, and has a specific section demonstrating how to delete unused or stale data sets using the DUMP command to a DUMMY DD. Use PARM='TYPRUN=NORUN' during your testing as you tweak your filters.

Answer (score 0):

[reference](http://www.mvsforums.com/helpboards/viewtopic.php?p=10235&sid=8ad1023193463e90e0426634620b693f)

```
//DELETE  EXEC PGM=ADRDSSU,PARM='UTILMSG=YES,TYPRUN=NORUN'
//OUTDD    DD  DUMMY
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
DUMp {DATASet | DS}(
               BY((selector,operator,arg){,(selector,operator,arg),...})
                {EXClude(dsn{,dsn,...})} {INClude(dsn{,dsn,...})}
               |
               EXClude(dsn{,dsn,...}) {INClude(dsn{,dsn,...})}
                {BY((selector,operator,arg){,(selector,operator,arg),...})}
               |
               {FILterdd | FDD}(ddn)
               {INDDname | IDD}(ddn) | {INDYnam | IDY}(vol{,unit})
               {OUTDDname | ODD}(ddn{,ddn,...) 
               {DELete}
```

in the above i can put my condition in the BY clause.. My query now is whether i need to put the file name that has the list of files i need to delete in the INCLUDE clause ?

Comment: You can either use the INCLUDE clause, or you can put the filtering information in a file pointed to with the FILTERDD(ddn) keyword. I must stress testing with PARM='TYPRUN=NORUN' many times to make sure you are deleting only what you want to delete. See the documentation on how to set up INCLUDE and BY filters.